# Numpy thermometer encoding

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use numpy optimized in-built functions to generate thermometer encoding. Thermometer encoding is basically generating *n* amount if 1's in a given length. For example in 8-length, 3 will be encoded as:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Using numpy to generate that vector based on a integer input is basically slicing and setting 1.

```
stream[:num_ones] = 1
```

So my question is given a *vector* as input what will be best way to generate a matrix output for instance:

```
[2 3 4 1]
```

as input should produce:

```
[[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0],
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0],
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0],
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

My current solution is iterating over the a zero matrix of required size and setting the required number of elements to 1 using the slicing method I wrote above. Is there a faster way for me to do this?

Answer (score 7):

I'd never heard of "thermometer encoding" before, but when you realise how it's so similar to one-hot encoding, it becomes clear you can get there using bit shift ops:

```
>>> a = np.array([2, 3, 4, 1], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> print(np.fliplr(np.unpackbits((1 << a) - 1).reshape(-1,8)))
[[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

*Edit:* You can generalise the idea to arbitrary size integers by working in 8 column chunks:

```
a = np.array([2, 13, 4, 0, 1, 17], dtype=np.uint8)
out = np.empty((len(a), 0), dtype=np.uint8)
while a.any():
    block = np.fliplr(np.unpackbits((1 << a) - 1).reshape(-1,8))
    out = np.concatenate([out, block], axis=1)
    a = np.where(a<8, 0, a-8)

print(out)
[[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: This is an incredibly cool solution. I didn't think about bit manipulation and then calling unpack. Unfortunately for my application I can have number of 1's be greater than 8. According to numpy docs, unpack does not work with uint16.

Comment: If you bit shift and modulus 256 you should be able to generalize the idea to arbitrary size integers by unpacking in 8-column chunks.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [22]: x = [2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 8]

In [23]: length = 8

In [24]: (np.arange(length) < np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1)).astype(int)
Out[24]:
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Or, create an array of the various lengths of "bars":

```
In [46]: k = np.arange(length + 1)

In [47]: bars = (k[:-1] < k.reshape(-1, 1)).astype(int)

In [48]: bars

Out[48]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

and use it as a lookup table:

```
In [49]: bars[x]
Out[49]:
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

In the above code, the preallocated array `bars` has shape `(length+1, length)`.  A more memory efficient representation of `bars` can be created using:

```
In [61]: from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

In [62]: u = np.zeros(2*length, dtype=int)

In [63]: u[length:] = 1

In [64]: bars = as_strided(u[length-1:], shape=(length+1, length), strides=(u.strides[0], -u.strides[0]))

In [65]: bars
Out[65]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Then `bars` is a view of the one-dimensional array `u`, and it only uses `2*length` integers.

Comment: Really clever and simple!  Now, why didn't I think of that, and instead came up with an insane hack ... :-\

Comment: Using an `as_strided` view as the template is inspired. Would probably work better than the standard `np.eye` method for one-hot encoding as well.

Answer (score 2):

Wim's answer is incredible. I also never heard of thermometer encoding, but if I were to do I would go with map. It's simply shorter without for loop solution. The performance is quite similar.

```
>>> def setValue(val):
      return np.append(np.ones(val), np.zeros(8-val))
>>> np.array(list(map(setValue, [2,3,4,5])))

array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

or one-liner with lambda function

```
>>> np.array(list(map(lambda v: np.append(np.ones(v), np.zeros(8-v)), [1,6,3,8])))

array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

not much different, listcomp inside an array creation function

```
temps = [1,2,4,1]
tlen = 8
np.stack([np.pad(np.ones(t), (0, tlen-t), 'constant') for t in temps])

Out[66]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```