# Is there a 'numpy' way to extend a 1D Numpy Array to 2D with the output values dependent on the original values?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numbers, call this "list", of length l, max N. The desired output is a numpy array shaped [l, N], where each row has list[row_index] 1s followed by 0s for the rest.

I've done it with a for loop, but I try to not use loops for non-sequential problems because numpy usually has a cool way of taking care of it.

Example:

```
Input: 
    N=5
    list = [3,
            2,
            4,
            2,
            1,
            0]

Desired Output:
    [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Way I've tried:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] = np.concatenate(np.ones(list[i]), np.zeros(N-list(i)))
```

I'm getting the right results, just feel like there's a more elegant 'numpy' way too. Any thoughts?

Comment: This representation is often called "thermometer encoding". Please refer to solutions on this SO thread: [Numpy thermometer encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49081578/710358)

Comment: `(np.c_[list]>np.r_[:N]).view('u1')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
l = [3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 0]
N = 5

np.where(np.arange(N) >= np.array(l)[np.newaxis].T, 0, 1)
```

This creates an array containing a range of numbers in the first dimension and another array based on `l` in the second dimension. Every element more than or equal to the corresponding element in `l` is set to 0, and every element less to 1.

This means, for example, that for the first element in `l` (3), there will be 3 elements in the result set to 1.

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```